# Is there an open source framework to draw complement of a PNG? Should be worked with Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, c, xcode, image-processing

Here is the requirement:

1. The input is a PNG A and a PNG B, the output should be PNG A minus PNG B (dig a hole with PNG B's shape on PNG A). I think this should be a draw complement action, and I need some library or framework to do that.
2. This framework should work with Xcode, and also can be used at various of plantforms(MAC/iOS/Win... etc). So I think it should be implemented by C/C++.
3. Any examples or codes should be a major plus to my problem... I really have no idea how to do that :(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
UIImage *imgA = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pngA.png"];
UIImage *imgB = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pngB.png"];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgA.size, NO, imgA.scale);
[imgA drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
[imgB drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationOut alpha:1.0f];
UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but I need a C/C++ implementation so it can be used cross-platform. Anyway, thanks for your quick reply:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mask to do this. http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

Try following code:

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {
    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
}
```